# Convert all DateTime fields in a complex object from local time zone to UTC

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I have a customer object which consist of all the details about the customer 
date of birth, join date, etc.

I want to convert all the date fields to Universal date time and store in a database.

Can anybody help me how take all the date field from the customer object and convert those to universal date time?

I Want a solution in such a way that when I call Customer.ChangeToUTC() all datetime field present in the customer should change to Universal time.

Comment: How is your tried code? which DAL you are using? EF or ADO.NET?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue. And in my case the solution was necessary because we have too many different complex models with `DateTime` fields.
For my needs I wrote the next extensions:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert all DateTime fields in a complex object from UTC to a destination time zone.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TInput">Type of an object that will be converted.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="obj">Object that will be deeply converted.</param>
    /// <param name="destTimeZone"><c>TimeZoneInfo</c> object of a destination time zone.</param>
    public static void DeepConvertFromUtc<TInput>(this TInput obj, TimeZoneInfo destTimeZone)
        where TInput : class
    {
        obj.DeepConvert(TimeZoneInfo.Utc, destTimeZone);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert all DateTime fields in a complex object from source time zone to UTC.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TInput">Type of an object that will be converted.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="obj">Object that will be deeply converted.</param>
    /// <param name="sourceTimeZone"><c>TimeZoneInfo</c> object of a source time zone.</param>
    public static void DeepConvertToUtc<TInput>(this TInput obj, TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone)
        where TInput : class
    {
        obj.DeepConvert(sourceTimeZone, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert all DateTime fields in a complex object from UTC to a destination time zone.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TInput">Type of an object that will be converted.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="obj">Object that will be deeply converted.</param>
    /// <param name="sourceTimeZone"><c>TimeZoneInfo</c> object of a source time zone.</param>
    /// <param name="destTimeZone"><c>TimeZoneInfo</c> object of a destination time zone.</param>
    public static void DeepConvertTime<TInput>(this TInput obj, TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone, TimeZoneInfo destTimeZone)
        where TInput : class
    {
        obj.DeepConvert(sourceTimeZone, destTimeZone);
    }

    private static void DeepConvert<TInput>(this TInput obj, TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone, TimeZoneInfo destTimeZone)
        where TInput : class
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var items = obj as ICollection;
        if (items != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                item.DeepConvert(sourceTimeZone, destTimeZone);
            }

            return;
        }

        var props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in props.Where(prop => !IsIgnore(prop)))
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                prop.ConvertDateTime(obj, sourceTimeZone, destTimeZone);
                continue;
            }

            var value = prop.GetValue(obj);
            var list = value as ICollection;
            if (list != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    item.DeepConvert(sourceTimeZone, destTimeZone);
                }

                continue;
            }

            // here I check that an object is located in one of my assemblies
            if (prop.PropertyType.Assembly.FullName.StartsWith("Should be your namespace"))
            {
                value.DeepConvert(sourceTimeZone, destTimeZone);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void ConvertDateTime<TInput>(this PropertyInfo prop, TInput obj, TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone, TimeZoneInfo destTimeZone)
        where TInput : class
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(obj);
        if (value != null)
        {
            var dateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)value, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
            value = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTime, sourceTimeZone, destTimeZone);

            var setMethod = prop.SetMethod;
            if (setMethod != null)
            {
                setMethod.Invoke(obj, new[] { value });
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool IsIgnore(this PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        var attr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<IgnoreUtcConversionAttribute>();
        return attr != null;
    }
}

public class IgnoreUtcConversionAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

You can use it pretty simple:

```
yourComplexObject.DeepConvertToUtc(TimeZoneInfo.Local);

// a collection could be converted as well
collection.DeepConvertToUtc(TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

Also you can get `TimeZineInfo` object from `FindSystemTimeZoneById` method:

```
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Belarus Standard Time");
yourComplexObject.DeepConvertToUtc(timeZoneInfo);
```

If you have two way refferences in your model, you have to decorate one refference with `[IgnoreUtcConversion]`:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime Birth { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

    [IgnoreUtcConversion]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple thing to do with:

```
TimeZone ltz = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;

DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;

DateTime t2 = ltz.ToUniversalTime(t1);
```

Comment: Note that conversions from local time to universal have the possibility of being ambiguous due to daylight saving changes. The framework handles this in an ["interesting" way](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime.aspx)

Comment: No, it's still going to be ambiguous. When the clocks go back, certain local times occur twice. (I'd strongly advise against using `TimeZone` at all these days; use `TimeZoneInfo` instead. It won't change the inherent ambiguity though.)

Comment: Ya...Thankx a lot..But I don't know how to go about it...@JonSkeet

Answer (score 1):

> Can anybody help me how take all the date field from the customer object and convert those to universal date time

Just do it manually. However, I *wouldn't* do it by reusing properties in the original `Customer` type. I'd either do it *before* you create the object (when you first get the data) or do it as part of a lightweight DTO just for database transmission.

Reasoning about date/time properties is hard enough when you *do* know how to interpret any particular property - if you don't know whether a property is going to be universal, local, or unspecified it's going to be much harder.

Things like *dates* don't even make much sense to think about as universal or not. For the sake of storing them in the database you may well want to create them explicitly using `DateTimeKind.Utc` to start with, but fundamentally a date is a date. One of the problems with the .NET framework is that it doesn't have a separate data type for dates.

I have a project called [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) which is an alternative date/time API for .NET. One option is to use that of course, but assuming you want to stick to the BCL types, I still think it would be worth reading our [concepts](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg/docs/userguide/concepts.html) and [type choices](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg/docs/userguide/type-choices.html) documents, to help you think about dates and times in the right way. It would be a good idea to work out which type you *would* use for each of the properties in your model, and then document that. You'll want to handle them differently in code.

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty simple if you are familiar with date times;

```
customer.BirthDate = customer.BirthDate.ToUniversalTime();
```

Just do the above for all your datefields and run an update query with a where clause on your customers ID number.

Comment: the problem is that when i add a new date filed to the customer then i have to call it as customer.newdatefiled=new custome.nedatefile.ToUniversalTime(). Instead I want to create a single function so that when i call customer.ConvertToUST() it should change all the date fields in the customer object to Universal datetime

Comment: First of all Thanks for your valuable informatiion. The problem is that when i add a new date filed to the customer then i have to call it as customer.newdatefiled=new custome.nedatefile.ToUniversalTime(). Instead I want to create a single function so that when i call customer.ConvertToUST() it should change all the date fields in the customer object to Universal datetime

Comment: @AbdulAdhar: Yes, when you add a field to your model, you have to do some work to make sure you handle it correctly throughout your app. That's to be expected. You *shouldn't* expect to be able to apply the same rules to all date/time-related values. As I say in my answer though, I'd recommend against using the same property for both universal and local date/times anyway.

Comment: If you want a function that changes all your dateTimes, you need to write a function that uses DateTime.ToUniversalTime() on all fields. There is no method built into .Net that will parse your object for DateTimes and convert them. You will need to call this method on all your date times.